# Breaking a stick to form a triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A stick is randomly broken into $n$ pieces. What is the minimum value of $n$ such that there always exists three pieces that can form a non-degenerate triangle? Preferably without calculus.

I know how to compute the probability of forming a triangle when $n=3$ but I don't think I can apply that to this problem.

Comment: A clearer definition of "randomly broken" is needed. Are the break points chosen from the whole stick at the start, chosen from a uniform distribution over the full length, or is only the first break done like this, with succeeding ones somehow dependent on what has gone before?

Comment: Suppose the stick randomly breaks into $n$ pieces of length 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...?  I don't think you can get "always" out of this. 

Also, computing the probability is subject to the same problems as the [Random Chord Paradox](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RandomChordParadox/).

Comment: @EdPegg Nice catch. I guess this question is done.

Comment: Switch the problem around -- what is the probability for n pieces?

Comment: @EdPegg: Interesting question!  Do you have an approach?

Comment: @GarryB: No, the question merely erroneously creates the impression that it's about randomness. It would be more clearly formulated with "randomly" replaced by "arbitrarily", since it's about *all* possible breaks allowing the formation of a triangle, not about probabilities. Thus, even if we take "randomly" literally, the distribution is irrelevant (as long as it has full support).

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Ed pointed out in a comment, the counterexample of a stick breaking into pieces with lengths given by the first $n$ powers of $2$ shows that the existence of three pieces that can form a non-degenerate triangle is not guaranteed for any $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for Ed Pegg's follow-on question: For $n = 3$, and the two breaking points chosen independently and uniformly from the unit interval, the probability is $1/4$.  Let the breaking points be $x$ and $y$.  Then the three pieces form a triangle if and only if

- $|x-y| < \frac{1}{2}$; *and*
- Either $x < \frac{1}{2} < y$, or $y < \frac{1}{2} < x$.

Plotting this area reveals the covered area to equal $1/4$.

I haven't given much thought to how straightforward it is to generalize this to larger $n$, though.  Of interest is the observation that the addition of a third breaking point can turn a qualifying set of three pieces into a *non*-qualifying set of four pieces.  For instance, suppose we have three pieces, of lengths $9/20, 7/20, 1/5$.  These clearly form a triangle.  But suppose the last break snaps the $1/5$ piece into two $1/10$ pieces.  Now, no three pieces can form a triangle, because the smallest of these will always be a $1/10$ piece, and that piece plus the middle piece can never exceed the largest piece.